# Why are there question marks instead of symbols when creating a DBF file using javadbf library?

Tags: java, groovy, dbf

I am using javadbf from github (link: https://github.com/albfernandez/javadbf) to create DBF files.
I cannot understand why, when writing a string field, instead of `«...»` I write `? ...?`
I use `fields [1] .setType (DBFDataType.CHARACTER)`, which corresponds to the "String" type and all characters must be written correctly.

Comment: Most probably, it's a matter of character sets / character encoding. The characters `«` and `»` are not part of the ASCII character set, and so are prone to show incompatibilities between different environments/libraries/tools. I don't know javadbf and how to configure its character set/encoding, so that's up to someone else.

Comment: This is an encoding problem.  It's very likely you are sending in those quotes as UTF-8 and your setup is either not configured or not able to handle this.

Comment: Where do you see what? In particular: where do you see the question marks?
And next: what encoding is used for the DBF files? UTF-8 or more likely a single byte encoding like ISO-8859-1, WINDOWS-1252 or, in worst case US-ASCII?

Comment: https://github.com/albfernandez/javadbf/issues/9#issuecomment-278400610

Comment: DBF does not support multibyte encodings like utf8. See link above that fully describes the issue.